# ScrollView Autolayout: Button on pinned to bottom - offscreen when rotated to landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've searched and couldn't find what I needed, feel free to close this if someone can point me to the right area or keywords to look into.

I have a scrollView with an email and password UITextfield, forgot password `UIButton`, login `UIButton` and a cancel `UIButton` as subviews. (Using IB)

When app is run in portrait everything looks and works fine. (ScrollView for `UITextfield` avoidance)
Currently portrait layout doesn't need to worry about avoiding the keyboard, however, when I rotate to landscape - I will need this.

My question is about AutoLayout and if anyone can provide hints, or something more to read to help get "*cancel button is a constant 20 from superview bottom (scrollView)*" See Images Below

- cancel button has a height equal to 30
- cancel button leading edge aligned to forgot password button
- cancel button trailing edge aligned to login button

previously attempted *cancel button constant 20 to superview bottom*, this didn't work.
tried a new approach, but seem to be stuck...

- cancel button top constant 181 to login bottom (750 priority)
- cancel button top <= 181 to login bottom (1000 priority)

Also, I can't post pictures... here are some links

[Portrait](http://tinypic.com/r/x6dhu8/8) and [Landscape](http://tinypic.com/r/2hqh5wn/8).

Ultimately, I'm trying to get better at AutoLayout and and I'm not sure exactly what's going on or how to fix it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/29eheep/8 - constraints in IB

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view doesn't handle orientation change that well, I've had the same situation going on for a while and I decided I handle the situation in code.

all I needed to do was to set scroll view's content size on orientation change.

Luckily you have a static layout and you can know the content size pre hand. constraints didn't work for me but they might be useful in many other ways.